# Docker. Can't start docker container with ssh command

Tags: bash, docker, ssh

I have command to run docker container --
`sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroiApks -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name=Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6 budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`

If i use this command locally - container will start up.

But i need use this command remotly(по ssh). And same command(but with adding ssh password) doesn't start docker container remotely.

`sudo sshpass -p "password" ssh akupyrev@<ip>  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroidApks -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name=Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6 budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1`

Error from console — docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

Tried to wrap command to '' - no effects.

UPD 1 ::
The main problem in  :::  -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6"
because without this option - container start ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, there is a **syntax issue** with `ssh`. Command to be executed remotely should be included between quotes, like so.

```sh
ssh user1@server1 'command2'
```

Moreover, based on your error, you might need to **escape spaces**

```sh
sudo sshpass -p "password" ssh akupyrev@<ip>  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroidApks -e DEVICE="Samsung\ Galaxy\ S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name=Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6 budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1'
```

Secondly, I am not quite sure if `sudo`'s password provisioned with `sshpass` will work. (you'll see)

Thirdly, wrapping `docker run` commands in **remote** ssh might not be the most robust and reliable way to deploy containers on you server. How would you i) go back ii) keep track of changes or iii) properly link containers together with such a hack? You would better explore systems such as [Helm](https://helm.sh/) or [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_container_module.html) to manage your containers

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.( 
Also mentioned that tried it.

Comment: but i think the main problem in -e DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S6"
because without this option - it's start ok 

Mb i can replace whitespace by some code ?

Comment: in you post, you mentioned using `"`, which conflict with the ones already present in your `docker run` command. you could try escaping spaces: `\ `

Comment: OMG . THank you . Could you please add to your answer?? 
Just add \ to whitespaces and it work. 
Final command 

`ssh akupyrev@10.19.8.90  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 6100:6080 -p 4743:4723 -p 5574:5554 -p 5575:5555 -v /home/androidApk:/root/AndroidApks -e DEVICE="Samsung\ Galaxy\ S6" -e APPIUM=true -e APPIUM_HOST="127.0.0.1" -e APPIUM_PORT=4723 --name=Samsung_Galaxy_S6-8.1-11.0.6 budtmo/docker-android-x86-8.1'`